# Match open CDATA section in Vim

Tags: xml, vim, cdata

Vim has the terrific shortcut `[{` for going to the last open `{` character. Is there a way to go to the last open CDATA tag in XML? Some thing similar to `?<!\[CDATA\[` does not work as there may be a close tag afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:call searchpair('<!\[CDATA\[', '', ']]>', 'b')`

Answer (score 0):

```
?<![CDATA[
```

will bring you to the last `<![CDATA[....` in current file. is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, Kent, but this will also bring me back to a `<![CDATA[` opening tag that is not left open.